# Is it bad form to split a conditional context?

Tags: python, caching, pickle

I'm adding caching functionality to a function that's basically an api wrapper. The gist of it is as follows:

```
def get_data(do_cache, *args):

    if do_cache:
        pkl_id = '/path/to/dir/' + get_cache_id(args) +'.pkl'

        try:
            data = read_data_from_pkl(pkl_id)
            return data
        except FileNotFoundException:
            pass

    data = get_data_from_api(args)

    if do_cache:
        cache_data_to_pkl(data, pkl_id)

    return data
```

I've split the `do_cache` contexts, since if this argument is set to `False` then I want to neither read from nor write to disk, just return the results to the api call.

This works of course, but I'm getting a bad "code smell". Not only is my IDE warning me that it can't be sure that the `cache_id` in the second conditional context has been created, but this just feels weird to me. Has anyone seen this approach create problems?

Comment: Where is `cache_id` coming from? I only see a `pkl_id`... typo? I would expect a `NameError` or unless there is a `cache_id` in a higher scope...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with splitting up conditionals like that; it's not uncommon for the condition variable to only affect parts of a function. I usually just assign a default value to the variable at the beginning to shut up the IDE's warnings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's a typo! thanks for pointing that out